# Problems with parsing rtl languages when a string ends with a direction agnostic character (eg. brackets)

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode, language-agnostic, right-to-left

When receiving an RTL string from a MySsql server that ends in a direction agnostic character, the first char (`string[0]`) in the string array switches to be the ending char as in the following example (which will hopefully render in the correct order here):

```cs
String str = "קוד (לדוגמה)";
Char a = str[0];
Char b = str[1];
```

In this example, `a`=( and `b`=ק, which is incorrect. `a` should = ק and `b` should = ו.

Using substring for character extraction yields the same result.
after further examination, I've learned RTL strings are kept as LTR behind the scenes with most programming languages. Using Unicode RTL symbol did not change the outcome.
This presents a unique problems for us, since in our ETL process which requires iterating through all chars (and not searching, since it appears regex can handle this use case), we can't differentiate whether the 1st char was indeed a bracket or other symbol, or was it the ending character.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be appreciated, as we couldn't find an answer relevant to our case thus far.

Edit:
It appears the example code has the same problem we encounter while being displayed using certain browsers.
the brackets are actually at the end of the string.
correct order: https://files.logoscdn.com/v1/files/35323612/content.png?signature=pvAgUwSaLB8WGf8u868Cv1eOqiM
Bug, which also happens with stack overflow display on some browsers: https://files.logoscdn.com/v1/files/35323580/content.png?signature=LNasMBU9NWEi_x3BeVSLG9FU5co

2nd edit:
After examination of MySql binaries, it appears the string in MySql starts with the bracket. However, I am unsure whether this is the proper way it should be stored, as every possible display we use (including but not limited to Visual Studio) displays it properly and other than char manipulation the strings acts as if the brackets are at the end.
So to phrase the question better: how do all these systems, including MySql workbench which is written in C# AFAIK, know whether to put the bracket at the beginning or the end?

Comment: As you've learned, Unicode strings are stored in "logical" order, and are only switched to RTL order for display. The Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/ is extremely complex, but does specify that bracket characters get reversed _for display only_ if they're in a RTL string. That is, `(` will be displayed as `)` but will still be the `(` character in C#. 
You've already shown in your example that `str[0] == '('` so I don't understand why you "can't differentiate whether the 1st char was indeed a bracket"; can you give more specific details?

Comment: As the string can also be LTR, the bracket position cannot properly be determined. It can also unfortunately be reversed, as I have no control over the input strings on this case and am dealing with huge amounts of data which can vary to a very large amount.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bracket position"? It should be at index 0 in the string. Are you talking about where it's displayed on the screen for RTL or LTR display? If so, that's a different issue and the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm applies. What exactly are you trying to determine?

Comment: You apparently have the same issue with your display in your browser as we have in our code. The bracket is actually written in the last position [11], however, it is moved to the 1st position [0]. Adding a pic to clarify. Edit: can't add pic due to low rep. Brackets are only surrounding the second word, not at the beginning.

Comment: It would probably help if you listed out what the codepoints actually are. If "brackets are only surrounding the second word" that makes me think your string is `05E7 05D5 05D3 0020 0028 05DC 05D3 05D5 05D2 05DE 05D4 0029`. However, you also wrote `a = str[0] = '('` which is clearly not true. Unless you're saying that the act of retrieving this data from MySQL Server changes the code unit order? BTW, you can post images to imgur and paste a link here.

Comment: Here's what I see in Google Chrome on Windows: https://files.logoscdn.com/v1/files/35323580/content.png?signature=LNasMBU9NWEi_x3BeVSLG9FU5co
Here's what I see in Edge and Firefox: https://files.logoscdn.com/v1/files/35323612/content.png?signature=pvAgUwSaLB8WGf8u868Cv1eOqiM
This is a bi-di rendering/display issue. The string is the same, the characters at `str[0]` and `str[11]` are the same. The characters (code units) in the string do not move around, even if the glyphs are displayed at different locations on the screen.

Comment: All string operations in C# are performed on the characters in logical order. So `Regex.IsMatch("קוד (לדוגמה)", @"^.+ \(.+\)$")` will be true even though the parentheses are reversed for display.

Comment: As posted with these pictures (adding them to the OP if you do not mind), the bracket reverses. Unfortunately, this is not only a display issue, ad the bracket can be found at the [0] position, while in fact, it should be at [11]. We theorise Regex.IsMatch works due to its string input reversing as well

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of checking, it appears a common convention when using unicode is storing the last character as first and vice versa in the case it's an LTR\unidirectional character in an RTL string.
The convention seems to differ a bit between text parsers, as evident between browsers. However, the 1st char IS indeed the bracket in our case. And in the case where it's the first character, it will end up being the LAST character.
I recommend just checking the handling of your own specific storage, parsers and libraries.